# Order of Tagged Questions irrelevant?

Tags: feature-request, canonical

When filtering by tags it doesn't appear that the order of the tags makes a difference. Eg [C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+.net) returns exactly the same page as [.NET, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net+c%23). While I agree with this, it means that both pages end up being indexed and coming up in search results. Would it be possible to add a canonical tag for these which orders the tags (eg alphabetically) so that search engines only index them once?

I'm not sure whether this counts as a bug or a feature request so I've tagged it as both.

Comment: Tags are automatically ordered LTR in descending order of popularity at the time the question was created or the tags were edited.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've been clear enough. I mean when you choose tags to filter questions by. It makes no difference in which order you select the tags as long as the same ones are selected. If you check the 2 pages I've linked to you'll see they are identical but they appear as 2 different pages to search engines.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I recall there used to be an algorithm in place to sort the tags so the resulting URL was the same in both cases, but this wreaked havoc with conditional searches so I think it was turned off. IMO, that was an implementation issue -- I'd support it if it got implemented correctly.

Comment: Indexing either page usually results in a bad search experience because the live page won't match the page that was indexed.

Comment: That's true. I suppose if that's the case then the pages should be marked accordingly. I suppose it makes more sense to only index the questions and answers directly rather than the summary/list pages.